# Как проверить существует ли пользователь с таким же именем в БД?

Tags: python, django

Я написал код для регистрации. Когда я 2-й раз ввожу одно и то же имя пользователя выбрасывается ошибка: UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username. Как уже понятно она из-за того, что в базе данных уже есть запись с таким именем.

Как проверить существует ли пользователь с таким же именем в БД? Если да, то просто культурно отобразить соответствующий текст на сайте

Код вьюхи:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class LoginView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "registration/login.html"

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = {}
        if request.method == 'POST':
            username = request.POST['username']
            password = request.POST['password']
            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect(reverse("profile"))
            else:
                context['error'] = "Логин или пароль неправильные"
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)


def index(request):
      return render(request, 'registration/home.html')


class ProfilePage(TemplateView):
    template_name = "registration/profile.html"      


class RegisterView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "registration/register.html"  
    

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            username = request.POST.get('username')
            email = request.POST.get('email')
            password = request.POST.get('password')
            password2 = request.POST.get('password2')


                if password == password2:
                    User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
                    return redirect(reverse("login"))

        return render(request, self.template_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

используйте [`exsist()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists)

```
class RegisterView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "registration/register.html"  
    

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            username = request.POST.get('username')
            email = request.POST.get('email')
            password = request.POST.get('password')
            password2 = request.POST.get('password2')


                if password == password2:
                    if not User.objects.filter(username=username).exsist():
                        User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
                        return redirect(reverse("login"))
                    else:
                        context['error'] = "Пользователь с таки логином уже существует"
                        return render(request, context)

        return render(request, self.template_name)
```

как-то так(возможно ошибся с выводом ошибки).